# Searching array of Dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am getting data from a server using api call. After using **NSJSONSerialization**

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

I get arrays of dictionaries.

> ({day = 0;hour = 0;value = 1; },{day = 0;hour = 1;value = 1;},day = 0;hour =2;val=0;},{day = 0;hour = 3;value = 0;})

Where I can iterate through each of dict using nested for loops. But what I ideally want is to extract 'day' and 'hour' where value is '1'.
Not above array of dictionaries are only for demo purposes. Actual array has 24*7 dictionaries item to account for each hour in each day of the week. My ultimate goal is to extract the time slots where value is 1. 
For example on 'day' 0 value is '1' between hour 0 to hour 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a predicate with format `value == 1`

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value == 1"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [jsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);
```

Comment: it did the job. Although to get the hours for each day i duplicated the predicate as below.        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value == 1"];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [jsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"day ==0"];
    NSArray *filteredArray2 = [filteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate2];
    NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray2);    is there a clearer way

Comment: Yes, use only **one** predicate with format `@"value == 1 && day == 0"`

Comment: Just add `valueForKey`. It's a key-value coding method which returns an array of all values for the given key: `NSArray *filteredArray = [[jsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] valueForKey:@"hour"];`

Comment: great it worked. Although I did manage to find long and messy solution.   NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for (NSDictionary *item in filteredArray)
   {
              [array addObject:[item objectForKey:@"hour"]];
   }
both results in desired output but your solution is more elegant. Thanks.

Comment: i got this as my filteredArray  (
    0,
    1,
    2,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    13,
    14
)  I need to get 3 time slots int startTime1, endTime1, startTime2,endTime2, startTime3,endTime3;  first one is from hour 0-2, second is from 7-9 and third one is from 13-14.  what i am trying is something on these lines   for(int i = 1 ; i<filteredArray.count; i ++ ){


        if(filteredArray[i+1] - filteredArray[i] > 0){
            endTime1 = filteredArray[i];


        }
    
        
    } do you know any neater way ?

Answer (score 0):

> Create an predicate, which will check if dictionary have `value: 1`. Then filter your `jsonArray` with this predicate as following:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
  // EvaluatedObject will be dictionary object while applied on jsonArray
  return [evaluatedObject[@"value"] intValue] == 1;
}];
filteredarr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[jsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```